# Connecting to Mongo Cluster with Spring Application

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

---

I have this simple Spring Boot Application and I'm trying to connect to a MongoDB Cluster.

```
 <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

As I thought it wasn't necessary, I do not have any MongoConfig.java in my project. All I have is a Mongo URI at **application.properties** file, as you can see:

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://admin:**<my-pass>**@shakespeare-url-cluster.lwkaf.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

So, when the application starts, the following exception happens:

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:619) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:497) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:328) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:278) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestMessage.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestConsumer.consume(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:494) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2020-12-08 11:25:00.365  INFO 3552 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-00.lwkaf.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:619) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:497) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:328) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:278) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestMessage.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestConsumer.consume(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:494) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted

2020-12-08 11:25:00.365  INFO 3552 --- [ngodb.net:27017] org.mongodb.driver.cluster               : Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-01.lwkaf.mongodb.net:27017

com.mongodb.MongoSocketWriteException: Exception sending message
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.translateWriteException(InternalStreamConnection.java:619) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:497) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendCommandMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:328) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:278) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:107) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.lookupServerDescription(DefaultServerMonitor.java:188) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:144) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: extension (5) should not be presented in certificate_request
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLExtensions.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestMessage.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.CertificateRequest$T13CertificateRequestConsumer.consume(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLHandshake.consume(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.ensureNegotiated(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl$AppOutputStream.write(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.write(SocketStream.java:99) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:494) ~[mongodb-driver-core-4.1.1.jar:na]
    ... 10 common frames omitted
```

I already tried to set up a new cluster and even to delete my source code, as I thought it could be a problem with my entities/repos/services). As you might suspect, it didn't resolve anything.

Answer (score 0):

add `-Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2` to your VM arguments and it will work fine 
if you have a DockerFile add it to ENTRYPOINT :

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2", "-jar", "pathToJar" ]
```